# sdkmanager Failed to download any source lists! UnknownFormatConversionException on Mac

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

it's been 4 days, none stop i'm working on this error and still no luck,
i'm building a project for unity Android (i have built this project 1933737728919 times before)
but i think due to some problems or changes i did to my java when i build for android it gives me this error:
[image]

[image]

so i digged dipper and tried to run the actual command unity is trying to run which is ./sdkmanager --list and i got the same exact error on terminal

[image]

things i did to fix it:

installed a new unity editor with android open jdk support (unity 2022.3 , 2021.3)

i installed android sdk from android studio

installed java on my machine (java 8, 11, 17)

installed java cmdtools separately and added to my android sdk

changed name of the folder that contains sdkmanager to (latest, the version)

changed my enviroment variables to this
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 17.0.10)
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

i'm currently on:

unity 2022.3.21
Macos M1
Java 17
Andoid SDK 32.0.0